# Databind can't contvert by IBindableComponent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using the VS2017 IDE, and DotNet4.5.2 and WinForm frameworks.

I want to display a value with a progress bar, so I wrote the following code and it works:

```
progressBar1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(ProgressBar.Maximum), source, nameof(source.Maximum));
progressBar1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(ProgressBar.Minimum), source, nameof(source.Minimum));
progressBar1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(ProgressBar.Value), source, nameof(source.Status)).Format += (sender,e) => {
    e.Value = (int)(e.Value as IStatus).Value;
};
```

I want to use the ToolStripProgressBar to display it, but because it cannot perform data binding, I defined a new class to inherit it and implement IBindableComponent as follows:

```
public class BindableToolStripProgressBar : ToolStripProgressBar, IBindableComponent
{
    private BindingContext bindingContext;
    private ControlBindingsCollection dataBindings;

    public BindingContext BindingContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                bindingContext = new BindingContext();
            }
            return bindingContext;
        }
        set
        {
            bindingContext = value;
        }
    }

    public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings
    {
        get
        {
            if (dataBindings == null)
            {
                dataBindings = new ControlBindingsCollection(this);
            }
            return dataBindings;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I changed the data binding object from ProgressBar to the newly defined BindableToolStripProgressBar, but this time running the application results in the throwing of a System.FormatException:

```
tspb.DataBindings.Add(nameof(ProgressBar.Maximum), source, nameof(source.Maximum));
tspb.DataBindings.Add(nameof(ProgressBar.Minimum), source, nameof(source.Minimum));
tspb.DataBindings.Add(nameof(ProgressBar.Value), source, nameof(source.Status)).Format += (sender, e) => {
    e.Value = (int)(e.Value as IStatus).Value; // Will be thrown FormatException
};
```

Is there anything wrong with my implementation of IBindableComponent?
Thanks in advace!

Comment: Well written first question. Well done!

Comment: Try to use `int.Parse((e.Value as IStatus).Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any)` in your event handler.

Comment: Still does not work, even if e.Value = 0. it seems that the problem is not here.

Comment: You don't need to create a new `ToolStripProgressBar`. Use its underlying `ProgressBar` for data-binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToolStripProgressBar` has a [`ProgessBar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprogressbar.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx) property which exposes the `ProgressBar` control which is hosted in the `ToolStripControlHost`. `Maximum`, `Minimum` and `Value` properties of the `ToolStripProgressBar` basically get or set corresponding property of the underlying `ProgressBar`.

So you can setup data-binding to the underlying `ProgressBar`:

```
Source source = new Source() { Minimum = 0, Maximum = 100, Value = 50 };
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var p = toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar;
    p.DataBindings.Add(nameof(p.Maximum), source, nameof(source.Maximum));
    p.DataBindings.Add(nameof(p.Minimum), source, nameof(source.Minimum));
    p.DataBindings.Add(nameof(p.Value), source, nameof(source.Value));
}
```